# How to make unique strings shorter and keep uniqueness

Tags: c++, linux, random

I have 4 bytes strings.

Each string is unique.

It is possible to cut each string (take only 2 bytes) and stay with unique sub strings? How?

I don't need more then 2^16 strings as output

Comment: What is technology you're using? Add it as a tag please.

Comment: @YassinHajaj - I added more tags

Comment: Only if the if each character in the original string is not allowed to take the full range of possible values.

Comment: @Mat - No I don't need more then 2^16 strings as output. added clarification.

Comment: You might get a more sensible answer if we know a bit more about how your strings are structured and how many (just alphanumeric? just alpha? hex? is there a pattern? do they fall into logical groups?)

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-dirty way is to map your strings to monotonically increasing identifiers or *codes*:

```
// std::uint16_t is a 2-byte integral type
std::map<String, std::uint16_t> stringsToCodes;
std::map<std::uint16_t, String> codesToStrings;
std::uint16_t counter = 0;
for (auto& str : all_your_strings) {
  stringsToCodes[str] = counter;
  codesToStrings[counter] = str;
  counter++;
}
```

You can then use `stringsToCodes` and `codesToStrings` to convert between the two.

If you have a more reasonable scheme to your strings there may be a better option than this. This method is sensitive to changes in how you store your strings and may not be desirable.